# Diagonal approximation of the inverse Hessian matrix

Tags: inverse, approximation, hessian-matrix

While reading chapter 5 of *Data Networks* [[1]](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Routing_Data_Nets.pdf) by Bertsekas and Gallager, I came across the following statement (p. 467):

> A simple choice that often works well is to take $B^k$ as a diagonal approximation to the inverse Hessian, that is
>   $$B^k=\begin{pmatrix}\left(\frac{\partial^2f(x^k)}{\partial x_1^2}\right)^{-1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \left(\frac{\partial^2f(x^k)}{\partial x_2^2}\right)^{-1} & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \left(\frac{\partial^2f(x^k)}{\partial x_n^2}\right)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

How can such a matrix be a good approximation of the Hessian matrix of $f$ at point $x^k$, assuming that for all $x$, $\nabla^2f(x)$ is a positive semidefinite matrix that depends continuously on $x$ ?

Comment: Has anyone looked at $\|H.$diagonal$\, / \, \|H\|$ for any real problems ?

Answer (score 1):

The statement should probably be viewed in the context of the book. When e.g. the matrix is [diagonally dominated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) you may use the diagonal inverse to calculate the inverse using a von Neumann series. So it is 'sort' of an approximation. Better if the diagonal elements dominate with some large factor the other elements. But in general, you are right that the formula need not make sense.

Comment: Besides the mentioned assumption, there is no additional information about $\nabla^2f(x)$. However, this kind of approximation seems to be valid in many cases (the only paper I managed to find on this subject is [this one](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/523476.pdf))...

Comment: In the context of data-network, there may be an interpretation as to different nodes having little correlations compared to the 'auto-correlation' within a node?

Comment: I don't think this approximation is restricted to the context of data networks, nor to the routing problem, as it seems to be some kind of "empirical result" used in the more general context of the gradient projection optimization method.

Answer (score 0):

It can be derived as a consequence for Kolmogorov-Frechet Theorems. Take some U-statistic and derive it as a symmetric, measurable (invertible without expansion of the domain), which has a bounded quadratic integrated value.(Consider Cauchy-Schwarz Theorem and some measure theoretic results)- (Mann-Whitney U Test- Rank sum test will be a good approx.) The resulting functions are differentiable with respect to Arzelo Ascoli Theorems. Derive the Hessian matrix and by Young´s Theorem. Notice, that any partial differentiation of this sort will yield ordinal results of the same domain. (Young´s theorem implies the neighborhood of size 1 of a variable of differentiation will alone imply the strong continuity with reference to the the Integral of the derivative.)

By the approximation theorems, see, that any differentiation with reference to a variable of your choice won´t effect its ordinality in their domain; hence, the invertibility with respect to some squared integrated mean or median. This obeys the invertibility conditions and the arithmatic mean linearity at the same time. You have a diagonal, hence a normal matrix (Consider solvebility of a characteristic function with regards to its eigenvalues.)

Comment: This sounds interesting but is hard to follow - could you expand on this answer?